# Sum case when one result bigger than the other

Tags: sql, report, sum, case

I'm using SQL report builder and wish to calculate the % within turnaround times

my table looks like

```
Name  count  within tat
jeff   1      1
jeff   1      0
jeff   1      1
jeff   1      0
```

i would like it to look like this.

```
Name  count  within tat
jeff   4     2 (50%)
```

The code im using to calculate within tat is

```
case
when (convert(Decimal(10,2),
    (cast(datediff(minute,
        (CAST(RequestDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(RequestTime AS DATETIME)), 
    REQUEST_TESTLINES.AuthDateTime)as float)/60/24))) > 
    EXP_TAT then '1' else '0' end as [withintat]
```

How can I sum this column ?

Comment: How do you get count 4 from that table?

Comment: And to sum it, just put a big ol' `SUM()` around the whole thing (minus the alias of course). Or does that not work?

Comment: Jeff is in the column 4 times

Comment: Ok so that "feff" is a typo then. Does using `SUM` not work? If so what error do you get?

Comment: the sum() doesnt seem to work

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" = ???

Comment: Is "count" actually in the table? For totals, it's actually a sum, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you looking for something like that?

```
select name , sum(count) total, sum(within_tat)*100 /sum(count) as percent

from Table1
Group by name
```

[**LOOK DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d6a6/4)

EDIT.

OR if you want it exactly as yyou want try this

```
 select name , sum(count) as total, CONCAT(sum(within_tat),' ' ,'(',sum(within_tat)*100 /sum(count),  '%',')' ) as percent

from Table1
Group by name
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d6a6/9)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in another `SELECT`.

```
SELECT SUM(count), SUM(withintat)
FROM (/*Your original query*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use case statment inside sum()

but it would need to return a number..

a change in your "within tat" to something like

```
select case when (convert(Decimal(10,2),
                 (cast(datediff(minute,
                 (CAST(RequestDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(RequestTime AS DATETIME)), 
                 REQUEST_TESTLINES.AuthDateTime)as float)/60/24))) > 
                 EXP_TAT 
            then 1 
            else 0 end as [withintat]
        ....
```

but, if you need the sum and the percentual.

you will need to use this value two times.

and I am sure you dont want to keep replicate code.

so use your actual query as a sub query to sum it may be a good idea...

if you realy dont want to use it as a subquery

you should use a outer apply to gather the value of withintat, doing something like this

```
 select Name
       ,count(*) as [count]
       ,sum(OA.[withintat]) as [withintat]
       ,sum(OA.[withintat])*100/count(*) as [percent]
       ,cast(sum(OA.[withintat]) as varchar(max))+' ('+cast(sum(OA.[withintat])*100/count(*) as varchar(max))+' %)' as [withintat_and_percent]
 from your_actual_query
 outer apply(select case when (convert(Decimal(10,2),
                              (cast(datediff(minute,
                              (CAST(RequestDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(RequestTime AS DATETIME)), 
                              REQUEST_TESTLINES.AuthDateTime)as float)/60/24))) > EXP_TAT 
            then 1 
            else 0 end as [withintat]
 )OA
 where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `IF` in this case (pun aside). I tried to reduce the complexity of your comparison, but without seeing some actual data, it's a best guess.

```
   select 
   name, 
   count(name) as count, 
   concat(
      sum(if(datediff(minute, 
             (cast(RequestDate AS DATETIME) + 
              cast(RequestTime AS DATETIME)),
             REQUEST_TESTLINES.AuthDateTime) / 60 / 24 > EXP_TAT, 1, 0 )),
      ' (',
      format(
         (sum(if(datediff(minute, 
                 (cast(RequestDate AS DATETIME) + 
                  cast(RequestTime AS DATETIME)),
                 REQUEST_TESTLINES.AuthDateTime) / 60 / 24 > EXP_TAT, 1, 0 )        
            )/count(name))*100,1),
      '%)'
   ) as 'within tat'
```